# forkmanager fork() function is unimplemented on this machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, windows-7-x64

when use forkmanager by ruby .it happen this: 
ruby version:
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x64-mingw32]
system version:
windows7 64
Uncaught exception: fork() function is unimplemented on this machine
D:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/parallel-forkmanager-2.0.1/lib/parallel/forkmanager.rb:525:in `fork'
D:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/parallel-forkmanager-
2.0.1/lib/parallel/forkmanager.rb:525:in`start'

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#encoding: UTF-8
# 抓取每一个站点的首页链接数量

require 'rubygems'          
require 'ap'               
require 'json'
require 'net/http'
require 'nokogiri'         
require 'forkmanager'       
require 'beanstalk-client'  

class MultipleCrawler

    class Crawler
        def initialize(user_agent, redirect_limit=1)
            @user_agent = user_agent
            @redirect_limit = redirect_limit
            @timeout = 20
        end
        attr_accessor :user_agent, :redirect_limit, :timeout

        def fetch(website)
            print "Pid:#{Process.pid}, fetch: #{website}\n"
            redirect, url = @redirect_limit, website
            start_time = Time.now
            redirecting = false
            begin
                begin
                    uri = URI.parse(url)
                    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
                    req.add_field('User-Agent', @user_agent)
                    res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
                        http.read_timeout = @timeout
                        http.request(req)
                    end
                    if res.header['location'] # 遇到重定向，则url设定为location，再次抓取
                        url = res.header['location'] 
                        redirecting = true
                    end
                    redirect -= 1
                end while redirecting and redirect>=0
                opened_time = (Time.now - start_time).round(4) # 统计打开网站耗时
                encoding = res.body.scan(/<meta.+?charset=["'\s]*([\w-]+)/i)[0]
                encoding = encoding ? encoding[0].upcase : 'GB18030'
                html = 'UTF-8'==encoding ? res.body : res.body.force_encoding('GB2312'==encoding || 'GBK'==encoding ? 'GB18030' : encoding).encode('UTF-8') 
                doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
                processed_time = (Time.now - start_time - opened_time).round(4) # 统计分析链接耗时, 1.8.7, ('%.4f' % float).to_f 替换 round(4)
                [opened_time, processed_time, doc.css('a[@href]').size, res.header['server']]
            rescue =>e
                e.message  
            end
        end
    end

    def initialize(websites, beanstalk_jobs, pm_max=1, user_agent='', redirect_limit=1)
        @websites = websites                # 网址数组 
        @beanstalk_jobs = beanstalk_jobs    # beanstalk服务器地址和管道参数
        @pm_max = pm_max                    # 最大并行运行进程数
        @user_agent = user_agent            # user_agent 伪装成浏览器访问
        @redirect_limit = redirect_limit    # 允许最大重定向次数

        @ipc_reader, @ipc_writer = IO.pipe # 缓存结果的 ipc 管道
    end

    attr_accessor :user_agent, :redirect_limit

    def init_beanstalk_jobs # 准备beanstalk任务
        beanstalk = Beanstalk::Pool.new(*@beanstalk_jobs)
        #清空beanstalk的残留消息队列
        begin
            while job = beanstalk.reserve(0.1) 
                job.delete
            end
        rescue Beanstalk::TimedOut
            print "Beanstalk queues cleared!\n"
        end
        @websites.size.times{|i| beanstalk.put(i)} # 将所有的任务压栈
        beanstalk.close
        rescue => e 
            puts e 
            exit
    end

    def process_jobs # 处理任务
        start_time = Time.now
        pm = Parallel::ForkManager.new(@pm_max)
        @pm_max.times do |i|
            # 启动后，立刻 next 不会等待进程执行完，这样才可以并行运算
            pm.start(i) and next 
            beanstalk = Beanstalk::Pool.new(*@beanstalk_jobs)
            # 关闭读取管道，子进程只返回数据
            @ipc_reader.close  
            loop{ 
                begin
                    # 检测超时为0.1秒，因为任务以前提前压栈
                    job = beanstalk.reserve(0.1) 
                    index = job.body
                    job.delete
                    website = @websites[index.to_i]
                    result = Crawler.new(@user_agent).fetch(website)
                    @ipc_writer.puts( ({website=>result}).to_json )
                rescue Beanstalk::DeadlineSoonError, Beanstalk::TimedOut, SystemExit, Interrupt
                    break
                end
            }
            @ipc_writer.close
            pm.finish(0)    
        end
        @ipc_writer.close
        begin
             # 等待所有子进程处理完毕 
            pm.wait_all_children 
            # 遇到中断，打印消息      
        rescue SystemExit, Interrupt    
            print "Interrupt wait all children!\n"
        ensure
            results = read_results
             # 打印处理结果
            ap results, :indent => -4 , :index=>false
            print "Process end, total: #{@websites.size}, crawled: #{results.size}, time: #{'%.4f' % (Time.now - start_time)}s.\n"
        end
    end

    def read_results # 通过管道读取子进程抓取返回的数据
        results = {}
        while result = @ipc_reader.gets
            results.merge! JSON.parse(result)
        end
        @ipc_reader.close
        results
    end

    def run # 运行入口
        init_beanstalk_jobs
        process_jobs
    end
end

websites = %w(
http://www.51buy.com/ http://www.360buy.com/ http://www.tmall.com/ http://www.taobao.com/
http://china.alibaba.com/ http://www.paipai.com/ http://shop.qq.com/ http://www.lightinthebox.com/
http://www.amazon.cn/ http://www.newegg.com.cn/ http://www.vancl.com/ http://www.yihaodian.com/ 
http://www.dangdang.com/ http://www.m18.com/ http://www.suning.com/ http://www.hstyle.com/
)

beanstalk_jobs = [['127.0.0.1:11300'],'crawler-jobs']
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'
pm_max = 10

MultipleCrawler.new(websites, beanstalk_jobs, pm_max, user_agent).run
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be running this on a Windows PC.

**fork** is a POSIX/Unix system call and is therefore only available on
POSIX/Unix systems.

A possible solution would be to use [Cygwyn](https://www.cygwin.com/) on your Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Rails test guides, section 3.2](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#parallel-testing-with-threads) to change workers -- which use the said fork(method) to paralleled processes -- to threads. This last one use another method to parallel processes. Also take a look on the beginning of the section 3, which describes how the tests are made.
I have used a WSL2 to run Rails. However the local test needs the jruby to be executed in somewhat.

To change the parallelization method to use threads over forks put the following in your test_helper.rb

`class ActiveSupport::TestCase`

`parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors, with: :threads)`

`end`

After, specify in your command `rails test` how much workers you need, such as `PARALLEL_WORKERS=1 rails test` or `PARALLEL_WORKERS=15 rails test`.